# Find all polynomials $P(x)$ of the lowest degree with rational coefficients that satisfy $P({3}^{1/3}+{9}^{1/3})=3+{3}^{1/3}$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

> Find all polynomials $P(x)$ of the lowest degree with rational coefficients that satisfy $P({3}^{1/3}+{9}^{1/3})=3+{3}^{1/3}$

My attempt:
$x={3}^{1/3}+{9}^{1/3}$

Squaring both sides, we get
${x}^{2}={9}^{1/3}+{81}^{1/3}+6
\\={9}^{1/3}+3.{3}^{1/3}+6
\\=x+2(3+{3}^{1/3})
\\=\frac{1}{2}x(x-1)=3+{3}^{1/3}$

The correct answer is $\frac{1}{2}x(x-1)$.
But I have reached to the above solution after reverse engineering the answer.My first instinct was to cube $x$. Is there any way I could have known beforehand that the question demands you to square both sides. Besides,**How do I prove that this is the only quadratic solution?**

Comment: You're trying to find a polynomial with the lowest degree, so since 0,1 don't work you'd try degree 2 and higher which means you'd have to square it at some point. As for proving it's the only one try $ax^2+bx+c=3+3^{1/3}$ where $x=3^{1/3}+3^{2/3}$

Comment: If you had a linear $P$, then $3^{1/3}$ would satisfy a quadratic, or linear, polynomial with rational coefficients. However, the minimal polynomial of $3^{1/3}$, over $\mathbb{Q}$, is $x^3-3$, which you can see is irreducible, by the rational root test, or [Eisenstein's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion) with the prime $3$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3389734

Comment: Thank you all. I got it